# Using SED: Find Regex > Replace With Match Groups

Tags: regex, sed, gnu

So I'm trying to restructure an access log to a particular format, I've already managed it in grok but learning sed sounds very useful so please humour me:

So, using SED I'm trying to find:

```
(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) - - \[(.*?)\] "(\w{3,4}) (\/.*?(\/|\.\w+)) (HTTP(S)?\/.*?)"(\d{3}) (\d+) "(.*?)" "(.*?)" "(.*?), (.*?)"(\[.*?\]) (\[.*?\])
```

And Replace with:

```
$12 - - [\2] "\3 \4" \8 \9 "$10" "$11"
```

Match in File(A) replaced lines sent to File(B)

I've tried:

```
sed -r -i 's/((\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) - - \[(.*?)\] "(\w{3,4}) (\/.*?(\/|\.\w+)) (HTTP(S)?\/.*?)"(\d{3}) (\d+) "(.*?)" "(.*?)" "(.*?), (.*?)"(\[.*?\]) (\[.*?\]))/$12 - - [\2] "\3 \4" \8 \9 "$10" "$11"/g;' fileA.txt > fileB.txt
```

To which it (GNU) throws the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

I'm afraid I'm totally new to sed so this is as far as my Googlefu has gotten me.

Input:

```
IPAddress1 - - [30/Mar/2017:11:33:55 +0100] "GET /image.jpg HTTP/1.1 "200 2607 "http://www.example.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36" "IPaddress2, IPAddress 3"[abc] [def]
```

Expected Output:

```
IPAddress2 - - [30/Mar/2017:11:33:55 +0100] "GET /image.jpg" 200 2607 "http://www.example.co.uk" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
```

Thank you kindly.

Comment: adding an example input with expected output would be helpful...preferably minimal example to find the issue...  some problems with regex: `sed` doesn't have `\d` use `[0-9]`.. and it doesn't support non-greedy `.*?`... `perl` might suit you better... not able to spot the error by just seeing the command

Comment: Ah good point, I'll add that now. I do know the Regex find and replace works by normal regex rules (e.g sublime text)

Comment: I tried the command and it doesn't show any error... and when you are using `-i` option, no point in re-directing output to another file... `normal regex rules` - I haven't used sublime, but `sed` uses BRE/ERE where `\d` and non-greedy don't exist

Comment: What kind of log is it ? It if from nginx ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make same changes in our regex to run it with sed.

I recommend you to use the `-r` parameter to can use [extended regex syntax](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/r/regex.htm), it is more easy for JavaScript|PHP|Java users.

Here is a little peace of your regex working:

```
echo \
'127.0.0.1 - - [30/Mar/2017:11:33:55 +0100] "GET /image.jpg HTTP/1.1 "200 2607 "http://www.example.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36" "IPaddress2, IPAddress 3"[abc] [def]' \
| sed -r 's/([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+) - - \[([0-9]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([0-9]+):/"\1", "\3", "\4", "\5"/g'
```

This example **is not completed**, it only for show you the **correct syntax**.